# disable kernel nterrupt for long cause reboot?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt, watchdog

In linux kernel, I have a block of code that needs to be executed with kernel interrupt disabled.

The code is enclosed in

spin_lock_irqsave();
spin_unlock_irqsave()

The execution time of the code is several seconds. Is this bad? Is it ok to disable kernel interrupt for seconds? When I run the code, the os reboots and the errors are

No errors detected
Boot info:
Last boot reason: watchdog

What does that mean?

Thanks

Comment: Technically, you could prevent a watchdog reboot by finding the code which resets the watchdog timer (probably something being periodically run from a timer interrupt) and making sure you do the same thing in your code at least often enough that the watchdog can never expire from neglect and reboot the system.  But you could well find that other issues result from having interrupts disabled that long.

Answer (score 1):

It's very bad idea to disable interrupts for seconds.

You must recreate your code using for example deferrable functions. You may use tasklets or workqueues for it. Disable interrupts only in those points where you really need it.

As you can see if you disable interrupts for such long time - the watchdog restarts your system. The watchdog restarts your system because it "think" that the system is frozen, because you disabled interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is seriously bad. It may cause "hard lockup" (but depends of your kernel config).
If it is possible create "bottom half" (good way), and use "hard" ops in these context, it may be preemptive. 
Also dont use scheduler routines in atomic context (upper bottom, interrupt handler), it will cause kernel panic.
You can find more info in Chapter 10: Interrupt Handling (https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)